# TYPO3 7.6 - is there any way to Override TYPES?

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

I am using user defined render types to add HTML Code or funktionlity to Dropdowns, ets. But can I also override text fields?

Example:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['formEngine']['nodeRegistry'][1476278844] = [
        'nodeName' => 'myNewSelect',
        'priority' => 40,
        'class' => \WFP2\MyExt\Form\Element\NewSelectElement::class,
    ];
```

In this class I derive from SelectMultipleSideBySideElement and now I can use the render method and Change the return of it.

But How to do this on other fields, which do not have a render type?

regards
n00n